# Dynamically delineate Excel cell

Tags: microsoft-excel

Is there a way to dynamically delineate an Excel text cell by semicolons such that the two words are then stacked in a column?

For example:

> word1;word2
>
> word3

becomes:

> word1
>
> word2
>
> word3

I cannot use macros or any sort of script/wizards. And I need it to be a formula so that it updates automatically/dynamically.

Is this possible?

Comment: Yes it is possible.

Comment: Is there a reasonable way to do it? I can do it in a super convoluted way. Can you elaborate on how? Thanks!

Comment: Are you open to a vba solution?

Comment: Thanks, but no, I can't use a VBA solution unfortunately.

Comment: You cannot do this without macros (vba coding).